# How do I use multiple filters in a group by in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, crosstab

Looking to create a reporting table that groups by date, but sums on several different filters.

Example, say I have multiple locations of a business and want to sum sales grouped by date.

So say source table

```
Date  |  Location  | Amount
===========================
Mon   |   One      | 10
Mon   |   Two      | 15
Mon   |   One      | 12
Tue   |   One      | 13
Tue   |   Three    | 17
```

I'd like to transform this into

```
Date  |  Location One Sales | Location Two Sales
================================================
Mon   |   22                | 15
Tue   |   13                | 0
```

Racking my brains on this right now and running into a wall.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` to conditionally select.

---

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f05af/3)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales
    ("Date" varchar(3), "Location" varchar(5), "Amount" int)
;

INSERT INTO Sales
    ("Date", "Location", "Amount")
VALUES
    ('Mon', 'One', 10),
    ('Mon', 'Two', 15),
    ('Mon', 'One', 12),
    ('Tue', 'One', 13),
    ('Tue', 'Three', 17)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT   "Date"
         , sum(case "Location" when 'One' then "Amount" else 0 end) as "Location One Sales"
         , sum(case "Location" when 'Two' then "Amount" else 0 end) as "Location Two Sales"
FROM     Sales
GROUP BY "Date"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f05af/3/0)**:

```
| Date | Location One Sales | Location Two Sales |
|------|--------------------|--------------------|
|  Mon |                 22 |                 15 |
|  Tue |                 13 |                  0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this data:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date TEXT,
    location TEXT,
    amount INT
);

INSERT INTO sales (date, location, amount) VALUES
('Mon', 'One', 10),
('Mon', 'Two', 15),
('Mon', 'One', 12),
('Tue', 'One', 13),
('Tue', 'Thr', 17)
;
```

You can manually build columns like so:

```
SELECT
date,
SUM(CASE WHEN location='One' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS loc_one,
SUM(CASE WHEN location='Two' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS loc_two
FROM 
  sales
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

But perhaps a more robust solution is to use group-by on both fields.

```
SELECT
date,
location,
SUM(amount)
FROM 
  sales
GROUP BY date, location
ORDER BY date, location;
```

SQLFiddle at: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7417e/9